# Calling a stored procedure to return value into variable

Tags: sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures, parameters, parameter-passing

Here is my procedure:

```
create procedure sj_busdays_prevmonth @dtStartDate datetime, @dtEnddate datetime--, @busdays_month int output
as 
return
SELECT Cast(
   (DATEDIFF(dd, @dtStartDate, @dtEndDate) + 1)
  -(DATEDIFF(wk, @dtStartDate, @dtEndDate) * 2)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @dtStartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @dtEndDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)as int)
```

Here is my statement:

```
declare @nBusDays int
declare @dtStartDate datetime
declare @dtEndDate datetime

SET @dtStartDate = cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(m,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()), 0)),111) as datetime)
SET @dtEndDate = cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(d,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0)),111) as datetime)

exec @nBusDays = sj_busdays_prevmonth @dtStartDate,@dtEndDate 

print @nBusDays
```

Here is my result:

```
0
```

It should be `23`,  What is going on here?

Comment: If you want data returned from a procedure you should use an OUTPUT parameter, not the return value. The return value of a procedure is used to indicate the execution status of the procedure. In your example I would actually suggest making this an inline table valued function instead of a procedure. It is more flexible than a procedure and as long as it is only a single statement like this they are super fast.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
return
SELECT Cast(...
```

To

```
RETURN Cast(...
```

As you need to return the result of the `CAST`.

(You could also `RETURN (SELECT ...)`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your stored procedure code as this -

```
create procedure sj_busdays_prevmonth @dtStartDate datetime, @dtEnddate datetime--,@busdays_month int output
as 
SELECT Cast(
   (DATEDIFF(dd, @dtStartDate, @dtEndDate) + 1)
  -(DATEDIFF(wk, @dtStartDate, @dtEndDate) * 2)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @dtStartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @dtEndDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)as int)
```

and then run your statements to get the desired result.
Or you may change the code like this too -

```
create procedure sj_busdays_prevmonth @dtStartDate datetime, @dtEnddate datetime,@busdays_month int output
as 
SELECT @busdays_month = Cast(
   (DATEDIFF(dd, @dtStartDate, @dtEndDate) + 1)
  -(DATEDIFF(wk, @dtStartDate, @dtEndDate) * 2)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @dtStartDate) = 'Sunday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  -(CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, @dtEndDate) = 'Saturday' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)as int)
```

and then invoke your statements -

```
declare @nBusDays int
declare @dtStartDate datetime
declare @dtEndDate datetime
SET @dtStartDate = cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(m,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()), 0)),111) as datetime)
SET @dtEndDate = cast(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(d,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE()),0)),111) as datetime)
exec sj_busdays_prevmonth @dtStartDate,@dtEndDate,@nBusDays OUT
print @nBusDays
```